# Swagger - describe JSON payload fields

Tags: java, rest, swagger

In a REST service using Swagger I have something like
`public UserResponse createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserRequest request)`

This `CreateUserRequest` is a POJO/bean.
It's passed in as JSON by the caller.

Are there any Swagger annotations to describe:
a) which of the POJO's fields are mandatory and which are optional
b) default values for the POJO's fields

I found such annotations e.g. for GET parameters but what if I need to describe the JSON payload/body?

I am using only annotations, no swagger YAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at annotation @ApiModelProperty, check swagger wiki for all annotations [swagger-annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/annotations)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

> Request bodies are typically used with “create” and “update” operations (POST, PUT, PATCH). For example, when creating a resource using POST or PUT, the request body usually contains the representation of the resource to be created. OpenAPI 3.0 provides the `requestBody` keyword to describe request bodies.

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body

> The `schema` keyword is used to describe the response body. A schema can define:
>
> - an `object` or an `array` — typically used with JSON and XML APIs,
> - a primitive data type such as a number or string – used for plain text responses,
> - a file – (see below).

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses

Comment: I found this page. But I do not have YAML. I have only annotations. I am not sure if I am using Open API 3. I am using swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar which I inherit from a parent POM. So I have no control over that.